# Distribution of elements Python

Tags: python, forms, distribution

I have text file(test.data), which include(this is just example other files have more values....)

```
4.5,3.5,U1
4.5,10.5,U2
4.5,6,U1
3.5,10.5,U2
3.5,10.5,U2
5,7,U1
7,6.5,U1
```

I need to make a table where in the first,second, etc. **column** are values and in last **column** is **class name**. For example in my case I want this:

```
4.5     3.5         U1
7         6.5         U1
5         7           U1
4.5     6           U1
3.5     10.5        U2
3.5     10.5        U2
4.5     10.5        U2
```

I started with reading file and read all data

```
import collections

f=open("primer.data",'r')

for line in f:
        print line
```

Any ideas how can I make this **for loop** for my problem? I know that I must look at last comma then this is last column(class name)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
for row in reader:
    print '\t'.join(row)

import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
result = []
for row in reader:
    result.append(row)
print result[0][1]
```

Comment: thanks that is what I need ;)  Can I now call from this table values for example 1. row, second element ??

Comment: you need to build a list for later retrieval

Comment: 1. always use `'rb'` for files that you pass to `csv` module. 2. you either don't need `csv` to read the file or you should use it for writing too (with for example `csv.excel_tab` dialect). 3. the output in the OP example is sorted (using 3rd column)

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.